# Why integer number is perceived as positive infinity?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python's interpreter understand int as positive infinity and i don't know why.

interpreter - Python 3.7
ide (does it any sense?) - PyCharm community 19.2.2

```
import unittest

def reverse(value):   
    reversed_value = int(0)  
    while value > 0:  
        reversed_value = reversed_value * 10 + value % 10  
        value /= 10  
    return reversed_value  


class TestEverything(unittest.TestCase):  
    def test_reverse(self):  
            self.assertEqual(reverse(0), 0)  
            self.assertEqual(reverse(121), 121)
```

Well, it works as planned with 0, but with 121 or any other positive integer n I get next:

```
n != inf

Expected :inf    
Actual   :n
```

As I understand, reverse() works right, but there is trouble in test and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Once you use `/`, you're using floats, not ints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you use `/`, you're using floats, not ints. With floats, your `value` can get smaller and smaller without reaching zero, so while loop carries on going, and your `reversed_value` gets higher and higher until it surpasses the range of floats and is given the value `inf`.

You can see this happening if you add `print(value, reversed_value)` into your `while` loop.

Try using

```
value //= 10 # int division
```

instead of

```
value /= 10 # float division
```